# R Plotly: 3D surface reverse x-axis

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to setup the camera of a 3D surface plot such that the x axis goes from from left = 0 to right = 60, and the y axis from bottom = 0 to top = 80, while having the z axis on the left side.

There goes an example:

```r
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>%
  add_surface() %>%
  layout(scene = list(camera=list()))
```

This is the default output:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

I tried to change the `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters from the `eye()` function without success. I also tried to use `xasix = list(autoarante = "reversed")`.

Comment: I tried changing the `eye` parameters for `camera` such as this: `camera=list(eye = list(x = .5, y = -2, z = 1.25))` it seems close to your desired plot? What do you think?

Comment: @Ben it works! Was not aware you could set negative values for the `eye`. Post your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `eye` vector determines the position of the camera, with a default of (x = 1.25, y = 1.25, z = 1.25).

To change the default to get the desired perspective, you can set the `y` in the `camera` `eye` to a negative value.

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>%
  add_surface() %>%
  layout(scene = list(camera=list(eye = list(x = .8, y = -2, z = 1.25))))
```

**Output**

[image: plotly plot of volcano with camera eye changed in layout]